# Wireless connects to wep network for 10 minutes then disconnects

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, troubleshooting

Windows XP desktop computer is able to connect to my home wireless network for about 10 minutes, but then it disconnects. It does reconnect after some time, but keeps disconnecting. Any way to troubleshoot and/or fix this issue?

I have checked the wireless network settings. WEP password and information is correct. XP is running SP3.

Wireless card is an Airlink101.

Comment: i'll piggyback on your question. same problem with an older 3-D Reach Wireless USB Adapter, tried different channels and cranked up the output power of the router (tomatoed WRT-54G), to no avail. definitely the adapter as other WLAN connections are rock solid

Comment: This same symptom happened to me last week, but it was due to my toddler son trying to pull the DSL line out of the wall.  He almost succeeded, but there was enough contact left that the connection lasted about 10 minutes on average before disappearing for a minute or two.  Check your house for toddlers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your router make?  Also, have you considered changing over to WPA from the poorly "protected" WEP? (Read up on its weaknesses [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy#Flaws) if you're not familiar). It's a long shot, but could someone unauthorized be hacking your WEP encryption?

EDIT: Also, this might be a good time to check the list of connected computers/devices on the router to make sure nobody is connected who shouldn't be.

Comment: This seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the Wireless Channel on the router.  There may be interference in the air causing bad data to drop the connection.  Also, Make sure you don't have your Cordless phone base sitting on top of your wireless router.

Comment: changed wireless channel from 5 to 11. There isn't a cordless phone base anywhere near the computer. Issue is still happening. This issue just started last night.